# Java applets and javascripts

Tags: javascript, ajax, applet

Can java applets pass data to javascript asynchronously without ajax (or is all the data contained in an applet server-side, so that javascript cannot see it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truly it is possible. Check the following two chapters of the Sun Applet tutorial:

- [Invoking JavaScript Code From an Applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) (this describes what you want)
- [Invoking Applet Methods From JavaScript Code](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) (this describes the other way round)

Comment: This is great...saves me the headache of having many ajax calls going back and forth. Thanks!